# CiviCrm - Users cannot register after update to Wordpress / Civicrm

Tags: wordpress, registration, username, passwords

I have just updated an existing site to on a staging domain on the same server.

Old version: WP: 5.7 CIVI 5.29

New version: WP: 5.8 CIVI 5.39

On the old site a user can register via a profile in a page using a shortcode.

In the new version the registration form exists BUT there is no Username / Password fields.

The profile settings has "Account creation required" checked.

Anyone can register in WP settings is checked.

I have deactivated other plugins and changed the theme - but this doesn't affect the issue.

I am loading the staging site in a clean browser - so I am NOT logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior changed slightly since 5.29.  CiviCRM now uses the account creation in WP where a password is not set and a link is set to the new user.   This is the preferred way to do account registration in WP.

I do see in testing this that your profile now must have an email field.  If the profile does not have an email field account creation won't work. Can you add an email field to the profile you are using?  That should solve your issue.

We'll need to document and potentially put up a change in CiviCRM to enable a primary email field if a profile does not have one and account creation is required.